# Remove new line from batch prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, prompt

I have the following prompt:

```
PS1="\[\033[s\033[0;0H\033[0;41m\033[K\033[1;33mCWD:\w | \d | \t | CM: \# | \V\s\033[0m\033[u\]
<\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]>\$"
```

Everytime I type a command, it types a new line after. How can I remove it?

The output is:

```
prompt->ls
a.c b.c d.c

prompt->
```

And I want it to be

```
prompt->ls
a.c b.c d.c
prompt->
```

Can this be done, while keeping the initial text on the top.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). You have received two almost identical answers.

Answer (score 1):

The *literal* newline character just before `<` is responsible. Remove it:

```
PS1="\[\033[s\033[0;0H\033[0;41m\033[K\033[1;33mCWD:\w | \d | \t | CM: \# | \V\s\033[0m\033[u\]<\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]>\$"
```

I think the newline was there to prevent the prompt-looking part of the prompt from overwriting the top line after `clear` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Comment: If I do that, the text on the top stays in front of the prompt